# How to distribute bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I've had a question of mine already answered, however, the help is really appreciated, I've awarded a bounty and would like to split it with 2 of the answers.

I can't see how, it appears as if I can only award 1 answer? The bounty is for 100 (as this was the minimum allowed) so I'd like to give 50 to 2 of the answers.

Comment: I would like to have possibility to split a bounty as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not possible. What you can do instead is start another bounty with the **Reward existing answer** reason, and award that bounty to the second answer.

Comment: Does this mean I'd have to award a total of 200 rep points though instead of a total of 100

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions You don't have to do anything, but if you insist on awarding both persons (part of) your bounty, then yes you'll have to spend another 100 reputation.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions "Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on)." [Beware of this!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)